# Is there any statistical overlap between people who identify as non-cis and people who have an unusual number of sex chromosomes?

Tags: research, sex, genetics, gender-sex-identity

The title kind of says it all.  I'm wondering if there has ever been a study of non-cis identifying individuals to see how many have sex chromosomes that were something other then XX or XY and if so rather an statistical overlap was found between the two groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fernández and colleagues appear to have addressed your question (2018. PMID [29892954](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29892954/)):

> To investigate the possible influence of karyotype on the etiology of Gender Dysphoria we carried out the cytogenetic analysis of karyotypes in 444 male-to-females (MtFs) and 273 female-to-males (FtMs) that attended the Gender Identity Units of Barcelona and Málaga (Spain) between 2000 and 2016... Our data showed a higher incidence of cytogenetic alterations in Gender Dysphoria (2.65%) than in the general population (0.53%) (p < 0.0001). ... In conclusion, we confirm a significantly high frequency of aneuploidy, specifically Klinefelter syndrome

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the full article, so I can't comment fully on potential limitations of the study. However, there is always the possibility of [ascertainment bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_bias).

Comment: Importantly, the other conclusion to draw from these data would be that >97% of those with gender dysphoria do *not* have aneuploidy.